# How can I destroy the Nav mesh agent

Tags: unity-game-engine, nav, mesh, destroy, agent

I am creating an fps game where the player has to kill enemies by shooting them.
I am using raycast to hit the enemy. I want to destroy the nav mesh agent when the raycast hits the enemy. I have a player script attached to the player(not a nav mesh agent) that throws a raycast.

How can I destroy the AI agent from the player script?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you'd like the enemy object to be destroyed when hit with the raycast from your player script. This Raycast snippet is shamelessly copied and slightly altered from https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

```
    // Bit shift the index of the layer (8) to get a bit mask
    int layerMask = 1 << 8;

    // This would cast rays only against colliders in layer 8.
    // But instead we want to collide against everything except layer 8. The ~ operator does this, it inverts a bitmask.
    layerMask = ~layerMask;

    RaycastHit hit;
    // Does the ray intersect any objects excluding the player layer
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))
    {
        Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject)
    }
```

In this scenario, if the raycast hits an object you will be given a reference to that hit and corresponding data via the "hit" variable. From there you can reference jump your way back to the colliding object's gameObject. Currently this code would simply destroy ANYTHING that the raycast hits. This is almost certainly undesirable. You'll have to add logic to be more discriminant.